# regular expression in javascript which allows backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My regular expression which allows characters, numbers, dot and underscore is

```
var numericReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+$/;
```

How could i allow backspace in this reg ex.?

Comment: What is the point in having *backspace* in regex? And what about *delete* then? I guess your problem can be solved in a different way, if you tell more about it.

Comment: the problem is when i press backspace in an empty textbox the regular expression validates it and throws error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution for this problem is to check the value of textbox >0 before validating. This will help to solve error showing while pressing backspace in an empty textbox..!!

Answer (score 22):

You can use `[\b]` to match backspace. So, just add it to your character class: -

```
var numericReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._\b]+$/;
```

Note that you don't need to escape `dot (.)` in character class. It has not special meaning in there.

**See also: -**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

for more escape sequences, and patterns in Regex.

Comment: @TimPietzcker.. I've not tested it, but it should work. And in that page it is mentioned somewhere down the table. Please take a look again. It says: - `[\b]`, matches backslash.

Comment: @RohitJain **It says: - [\b], matches `backslash`.** you meant backspace, right?

Comment: @NaveedS.. Aw! True. That typo again.

Comment: @Amith.. Did you try the regex I gave?

Comment: @Amith.. Well, what how are you trying to test it? How are you entering the backspace?

Comment: the problem is when i press backspace in an empty textbox the regular expression validates it and throws error

Comment: @Amith.. And what do you want it to do? What error it throws. Please post complete details, on what is the input, and expected output.

Comment: i have a text box in a form. on key press i'm validating not to enter special chars, numbers etc. if a user enter his name and what to remove it he presses backspace and when he delete the last char in the text box say amith and when deletes a and press backspace again its throwing validation error

Comment: @Amith: You should not run validation when the textbox doesn't have any text. The validation should still apply when the user click submit, though. The backspace character `\b` is not reflected in the text when you press backspace.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you rewrite your regex to :

```
var numericReg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+|[\b]+$/
```

Or:

```
var numericReg = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9._]|[\b])+$/
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Check against 'event.keyCode' and 'value.length' before checking the regular expression.
Keycode 8 = backslash

```
$('#my-input').on('keypress change', function(event) {
   // the value length without whitespaces:
   var value_length = $(this).val().trim().length;
   // check against minimum length and backspace
   if (value_length > 1 && event.keyCode != 8) {
      var regex = new RegExp('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._]+$/');
      var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also made a input type text that accept only numbers(non decimal) and backspace keyboard. I notice that putting [\b] in regular expression is not needed in non Firefox browser.

```
var regExpr = new RegExp("^[0-9,\b][0-9,\b]*$");
```