# Include backspace in Regex with textarea

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I have looked at this post to help me ([regular expression in javascript which allows backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473666/regular-expression-in-javascript-which-allows-backspace)), but still, I can not use my backspace to delete characters.

I have tried different variations with

```
(/[0-1,\b]/g) 
(/[0-1][\b]/g)
(/[0-1]+[\b]/g)
```

...nothing is working.

Here is my whole function:

```
binary.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key.match(/[0-1]/g)) {
    return event;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Event handler is attached to   `<textarea id="binary" placeholder="Binary..." type="text"></textarea>.`

I have tried to remove preventDefault(), but my regex does not apply then.

Comment: You can use `if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.key.match(/[01]/g))`

Comment: It is working, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if BACKSPACE is pressed by adding a `event.keyCode === 8 ||` alternative to the `if` condition.

Also, it is probably "cleaner" to use `RegExp.test()` to check if a regex matches a string, `/[01]/.test(event.key)`.

```js
let log  = document.querySelector('#log'),
    test = document.querySelector('#test');

test.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 8 || /[01]/.test(event.key)) {
    return event;
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
#test:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='test' autofocus /><br />
<span id='log'></span>
```